# How to setup AWS RDS standalone instance without traffic from actual RDS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We need to know what are the best options to set AWS RDS instance (Aurora mysql) that is standalone and does not get traffic from actual RDS cluster.

**Requirement** is for our data team to write analytical queries but we do not want it to impact actual application and DB performance. Hence we need a DB which always has near to live data but live traffic or application does not connect to this instance.

Need to know which fits better, DL clone OR AWS Pilot light OR AWS Warn standby OR AWS hot standby OR
multi-AZ configuration.

Kindly let us know which one would fit our requirement better.

**We have so far read about below 3 options**,

1. AWS Amazon Aurora DB clone, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html
2. AWS Pilot light or AWS Warn standby or AWS hot standby
   . https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/disaster-recovery-dr-architecture-on-aws-part-iii-pilot- light-and-warm-standby/
3. With multi-AZ configuration, we can create a new instance in new AZ, so that his instance will have a different host (kind off, a fail over strategy), where traffic to his instance will be from our queries and not from live prod application, unless there is some fail over issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1, Aurora cloning says

> Run workload-intensive operations, such as exporting data or running analytical queries on the clone.

...which seems to be your use case here.

Just be aware that the clone will not see any changes to the original data after it is made. So you will need to periodically delete and re-clone to get the updated data

Regarding option 2, I wrote [those blog posts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/disaster-recovery-dr-architecture-on-aws-part-iii-pilot-light-and-warm-standby/), and I do not think that approach suits your use case.  That approach is for disaster recovery

Option 3 may work. To modify it a bit, the concept here is to create an [Aurora Replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-replicas-adding.html), which as you say is a separate instance.  The problem here is the [reader endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Endpoints.Reader) for your production workload, it may hit that instance (which is not what you want)

EDIT: Adding new option 4

Option 4. Check out [Amazon Aurora zero-ETL integration with Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-aurora-zero-etl-integration-redshift/). This zero-ETL integration also enables you to analyze data from multiple Aurora database clusters in an Amazon Redshift  cluster.

Comment: Thanks @Seth E, For option 1 as you mentioned, if we delete and create a new clone, if it does the job, then will it cost us each time we delete and create a new clone, how is that billing handled?

Comment: Glad you found my answer helpful.  If you could mark it as correct, I would appreciate it.  As far as cost, know that cloning uses your existing data store, so there should be no additional charge for storage (if you write to the clone, then that differential data will incur a charge), so the only charge should be for I/O

Comment: in addition to IO costs, there will also be instance costs.